# PHP preg_match() doesn't find match

Tags: php, preg-match

I need to get the dates matching the format '**dd/mm**', but it doesn't seem to work :

```
$r = 'D 07/11 A 17/11';
$pattern = '/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])/';

if(preg_match($pattern, $r, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

The regex seems to be valid,i've tested it using https://regex101.com/.

Comment: `^` <- Anchor, remove it

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
There's another issue , i get as a result :
    Array ( [0] => 07/11 [1] => 07 [2] => 11 )
Why does it match the first date but not the second?

Comment: *preg_match* **_all**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `^` repexp character. It means: `(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-\/](0[1-9]|1[012])` must to be in the begining of string. Your regex will be valid on:

```
$r='07/11 A 17/11';
```

So, remove `^` character.